# Distributed tracing doesn't work Jaeger+OpenTelemetry

Tags: go, jaeger, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

I am trying to implement distributed tracing with basic GO client-server app. Using default Jaeger docker-compose all-in-one.
What was done to fix and doesn't help:

1. Changed `collector` to `agent` and `agent` to `collector`.
2. Checked logs, nothing about `"client"` there
3. Tried to inject headers (propagation)
4. Tried without injecting to headers (propagation)

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
import(
...
    tracesdk "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace"
...
)

func main() {
.....
    exporter, err := jaeger.New(
        jaeger.WithAgentEndpoint(
            jaeger.WithAgentHost("localhost"),
            jaeger.WithAgentPort("6831"),
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tp := tracesdk.NewTracerProvider(
        tracesdk.WithBatcher(exporter),
        tracesdk.WithResource(resource.NewWithAttributes(
            semconv.SchemaURL,
            semconv.ServiceNameKey.String("client"),
            semconv.ServiceVersionKey.String("1.0.0"),
            semconv.DeploymentEnvironmentKey.String("local"),
        )),
    )

    defer func() {
        if err := tp.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(
        propagation.TraceContext{},
        propagation.Baggage{},
        propagators.Jaeger{},
    ))
    .......
}
....
func fetcherSuccess() error {
    tr := otel.Tracer("clientHTTP")
    ctx, span := tr.Start(context.Background(), "client.fetcherSuccess")
    defer span.End()

    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, "http://localhost:8080/success", nil)
    if err != nil {
        AddSpanError(span, err)
        FailSpan(span, "request error")
        return err
    }
    // Try to inject headers to the context using this otel.GetTextMapPropagator().Inject(ctx, h)
    headers := InjectHTTPHeaders(ctx)
    for k, v := range headers {
        req.Header.Add(k, v)
    }

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    return nil
}
```

**SERVER CODE:**

```
import(
...
    tracesdk "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace"
...
)

func main() {
.....
    exporter, err := jaeger.New(
        jaeger.WithAgentEndpoint(
            jaeger.WithAgentHost("localhost"),
            jaeger.WithAgentPort("6831"),
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tp := tracesdk.NewTracerProvider(
        tracesdk.WithBatcher(exporter),
        tracesdk.WithResource(resource.NewWithAttributes(
            semconv.SchemaURL,
            semconv.ServiceNameKey.String("server"),
            semconv.ServiceVersionKey.String("1.0.0"),
            semconv.DeploymentEnvironmentKey.String("local"),
        )),
    )

    defer func() {
        if err := tp.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(
        propagation.TraceContext{},
        propagation.Baggage{},
        propagators.Jaeger{},
    ))

    if err := handleRequests(); err != nil {
        panic("unable to create handler")
    }
    .......
}

func handleRequests() error {
    router := http.NewServeMux()

    router.HandleFunc("/success", handleSuccess)
    router.HandleFunc("/error", handleError)
    fmt.Println("Server is listening on port: 8080")

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
....

func handleSuccess(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tr := otel.Tracer("serverHTTP")
    //Extract headers using otel.GetTextMapPropagator().Extract()
    ctx := ExtractHTTPHeaders(r.Context(), r.Header)
    ctx, span := tr.Start(ctx, "server.handleSuccess")

    defer span.End()

    //Add some tags here to help debug.
    AddSpanTags(span, map[string]string{"name": "Ivan"})

    //Add some event.
    AddSpanEvents(span, "testEvent", map[string]string{"eventInfo": "some info"})

    initCall(ctx, false)

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("done"))
}
```

In `Jaeger` UI I see only `"server"` spans but not `"client"`. So what I understand that for some reasons trace from `"client"` unable to reach the `agent/collector`(I tried both). Is there any problems with my code? `Jaeger` init seems equal why one app doesn't send anything is not clear for me.

Comment: Does your docker-compose file have the client in the same network as the server and collector?